# Application of Martingale Convergence Theorem

Tags: probability, martingales, stochastic-analysis

I am struggling with this question:

Let $X_n$ and $Y_n$ be positive integrable and adapted
to $ {\mathscr{F}}_n$.  Suppose that $E(X_{n+1} \mid \mathscr{F}_n) \le X_n+ Y_n$
with $\sum Y_n < \infty$ a.s.  Prove that $X_n$ converges
 a.s. to a finite limit.

The hint is to consider the stopping time
 $N = \inf_k \sum_{m=1}^k Y_m > M$. My first question is why and how to come up with such stopping time? I try to construct supermartingale and use the convergence theorem. Any suggestion?

Comment: I knew how to do it.

Comment: So you have solved the problem...?